# How to open huge csv files using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a huge `csv` file which size is `~1.2 GB`, and when I try to load this file using `Visual Studio Code`, getting this error: `Unable to open 'records.csv': Invalid string length`. How can I view the content of this file? Or are there any ways to view just `n` lines of this file through `VS Code` - something like the `tail` command of `Linux`?

Comment: If you're on Windows PowerShell's `import-csv` allows you to stream the content (ie. not all loaded at once) to look for issues

Comment: Great tip, thanks for that, @Richard. But actually I'm looking for a solution based on `VS Code` - of course, if it is possible.